# How I can create a simple XML import/export tool in WordPress

Tags: json, xml, wordpress, import, export

I am finding a simple easy to use PHP and `JavaScript/jQuery` "XML" file `import/export` tool in `WordPress`.

So I can export a file from certain WordPress options and Import to another site to set those options. `Import/Export` file can be an `XML/JSON` or any such other format file.

Comment: There are lot of plugins for Import/Export in WordPress.

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a custom solution. It can be very very basic.